# Yandex allure: test suite name in TestNG

Tags: testng, allure

How to specify test suite name in Yandex allure?
By default it shows class canonical name and that is not beauty at all..

[image: allure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem - TestNG suite has name (it's usually a class name), and xmlSuite has name too (it's string from your `testng.xml` or if you don't use such xml it's just a random string) and maybe some local parameters. So for now title that you see in report just a concatenation of these strings. You can try to get sample class name, so create issue in `allure-core` and lets discuss.

We don't use *TestNG* as much as *JUnit*, so it's supported mostly by the community

Answer (score 0):

Basically this name is derived from the test's classname without package. When I've got a test class called BrowsersAvailabilityTest in my report it appears as "Browsers availability test" just by itself.

Why it does not work in your case, it's hard to say. My guess is that there's something wrong with your JUnit setup. If you take a look at the sources [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-junit-adaptor/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/junit/AllureRunListener.java#L48) you will see that allure just uses test class name provided by JUnit. You may try to debug this source code to check whether I am right.

Maybe your JUnit version is just old or something... Wait, are you using JUnit?)

Comment: Thank you for your support,  I`ll try to change my configuretion.
I`m using TestNG.